# I am trying to use and learn the keyword "this" in java. In my code i got an error

Tags: java, this

The main goal of this code is to use this keyword and to set the global variable ( ten, zero, & twenty to equal int ten, int zero, int twenty.) So then i would call the method and it would add them together.( for a total value of 30)

```
package javaapplication53;

public class NewClass {

public int ten = 10;
public int zero = 0;
public int twenty = 20;

public int yourMethod(int ten, int zero, int twenty) {



    this.ten = ten;
    this.zero = zero;
    this.twenty = twenty;

   return(ten +zero+ twenty);
}
}
```

Then i called the constructor in my main method.

```
   package javaapplication53;

    public class JavaApplication53 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewClass nc = new NewClass();
    nc.NewClass(ten, zero, twenty);
}
```

}

It said i have to input 3 int, which i thought i did in the other class.

*I am a new to computer programming*

Comment: Can you paste the actual traceback?

Comment: don't you want to call nc.yourMethod(1,2,3) in the last line? The method NewClass() doesn't exist.

Comment: What is your intention by coding `nc.NewClass()`?

Comment: why are u calling constructor from class object ?

Comment: it was nc.NewClass(ten, zero, twenty); but there was red line under it. Saying cannot find symbol.

Answer (score 7):

You meant to call the method defined in NewClass-

So instead of-

```
nc.NewClass();
```

You may have wanted-

```
nc.yourMethod(n1, n2, n3); //where n1, n2, n3 are integers.
```

Example-

```
System.out.println(nc.yourMethod(50, 45, 89));
```

Also, maybe you wanted your NewClass to be like this because assigning new value to a method parameter is not a good practice:

```
public class NewClass {

    private int ten;
    private int zero;
    private int twenty;

    public int yourMethod(int ten, int zero, int twenty) {

        this.ten = ten;
        this.zero = zero;
        this.twenty = twenty;

        int sum = (this.ten + this.zero + this.twenty);

       return sum;
    }

}
```

If you want to avoid assigning new values to method parameters accidentally, you can use **final** like this which is a great practice-

```
public int yourMethod(final int ten, final int zero, final int twenty) {

    // code

}
```

Comment: +1 And `yourMethod` should not assign values to its own parameters.

Comment: Is it bad to assign values to you'r parameters, and is there a way to do it?

Comment: @pur3extrme That is why we used what we passed and removed these three statements from your code: ten = 4; zero = 5; twenty = 30;

Answer (score 1):

Are you by any chance trying to do this:

```
public class NewClass {

public int ten = 10;
public int zero = 0;
public int twenty = 20;

public int yourMethod(int ten, int zero, int twenty) {

    this.ten = ten;
    this.zero = zero;
    this.twenty = twenty;

   return(ten +zero+ twenty);
}
```

Test Class

```
Public class JavaApplication53 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewClass nc = new NewClass();
    nc.yourMethod(4,5,30)

}
```

are you trying to pass "4","5", and "30" into the calculation to return the sum of all of them? If you are, then the two classes should look better for you.
I got rid of the r,5, and 30 values from the top class and placed them in the second class as parameters to be passed when calling the "yourMethod" method. 
I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The way I learned "this" and "super" is with an IDE. When you highlight a variable in Eclipse/Netbeans, all the other places where that variable is mentioned is highlighted.

An accepted way of doing this:

Class:

```
public class NewClass {
    public int ten, zero, twenty;

    /* This is the constructor called when you do 
     * NewClass nameOfVar = new NewClass(blah, blah, blah);
     */
    public NewClass(int ten, int zero, int twenty) {
        this.ten = ten;
        this.zero = zero;
        this.twenty = twenty;
    }

    /* This method/function sums and returns the numbers */
    public int sum() {
       return ten + zero+ twenty;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class JavaApplication53 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewClass nc = new NewClass(10, 0, 20);
        System.out.println(nc.sum());
    }
}
```

The output would be 30.